# How to force download attachment

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to force download a zip attachment in WordPress.

```
$file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $name->name );

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"');
header("Content-Length: ".filesize( $file_url ));

readfile($file_url);
```

If I echo `$file_url` it outputs the correct URL. But the file is corrupted when I download. But if I set `$file_url` manually to the same URL, the file is not corrupted when downloading. Any ideas?

Comment: URL is not the same as a file path. Use the file path. Not the URL.

Comment: But if I enter `$file_url = "http://domain.com/files/file.zip"` it works. And if I echo `$file_url` it gives the same url.

Comment: Did you look at the headers you get back? `filesize` does not work for URLs.

Comment: Seems like `filesize` was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: It was a problem because it would tell the browser "I'm sending you a file now - it is 0 bytes long" and the browser then goes "OK - send it to me - thanks - I've received all 0 bytes. Bye". If you wish the progress to work you need to use the filesize (as I mentioned, just use the *path* instead of the URL)

Comment: Worked! Used `get_attached_file` instead of `wp_get_attachment_url` to get file path.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Feel free to respond to your own question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @h2ooooooo stated in a reply, [`filesize`](http://www.php.net/filesize) won't work with URL's. Needs to use [`get_attached_file`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file) instead of [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) to get path.

This worked:

```
$file_path = get_attached_file( $name->name );

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize( $file_path ));

readfile($file_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK but I feel there may be issue with `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"');`. It may possible that you have different file name as attachment and `test.zip` is hard coded. try to replace .

`header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"');`

with

`header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");`

and use `exit;` after `readfile($file_url);`

Comment: I will try, but keep in mind that this code works when I change the first line to `$file_url = "http://domain.com/files/file.zip"`.

Comment: can you print `wp_get_attachment_url( $name->name );` to check what are you getting?